# Clarification in definition of Holt-Winters algorithm

Tags: time-series, forecasting

The algorithm mentioned on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing) has a line $$s_t = \alpha \frac{x_t}{c_{t-L}} + (1-\alpha) (s_{t-1} + b_{t-1})$$.

For $1 < t < L$ how should we interpret $c_{t-L}$?  On that interval, should we replace it with $c_t$?

Answer (score 2):

For triple exponential smoothing it says that at least one seasonal cycle of length L must be completed. So t is actually greater than L.  The notation is 1 < t < L but the t is given modulo L.

Comment: Thanks, seems like we initialize $c_1 ... c_L$ in a certain way.  Suppose there are 10 whole periods with $L = 10$ so 100 data points.  After we initialize $c_1 ... c_{10}$, how do we compute $s_1$, which is a function of $c_{-9}$?

Comment: @JCWong My answer was partially hidden.  Read it now and see if it makes more sense.

Comment: The index $t$ is *not* understood modulo $L$. Use initial estimates as explained on the [NIST site](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section4/pmc435.htm).

Comment: @whuber That is how it is describe in the Wikipedia article provided by the OP.  Did you look at that?  That is what I was going by.

Comment: @Michael, not only did I look at it, I implemented the algorithm to make sure it made sense. Of course I could be mistaken: if you have a different interpretation, then please share your code with us to demonstrate how it really works.

Comment: @whuber All I was doing was explaining what i read in order to help the OP. It just seemed to me that you wouldn't have a C$_t$$_-$$_L$ for 0<t<L.  But would if the index t was modulo L.

Comment: @whuber, Sorry, after looking at NIST I still don't understand how the first few values of $s_t$ are initialized.  It makes sense that we need to see at least 1 season to initialize $c_1 ... c_L$, or $I_1 ... I_L$ using the NIST syntax.  After initializing c, we also initialize $b_1$, but how should $s_1 ... s_L$ be initialized?